# Updating App.Config does not update values when I re-run my c++ Program?

Tags: c++, config

I have a C++ program that uses a App.config file. It reads in values from this config and uses them in my program. When I stop my program, and updates values, it does not get reflected into my program when I re-run it.

My program files:

```
MyAppName.dll (Config)
App (Config, looks like txt file)
```

My questions are the following:

```
Why can't I use App.config to update the values.
Why is the MyAppName.dll a config file but is a .dll?
Is it bad to modify the MyAppName.dll to update the values?
```

Comment: Are you sure you are stopping and restarting the program? Or are you breaking and resuming execution? The most likely explanation is that you aren't executing the program a second time, so it isn't reading the config file.

Comment: @TimRandall Yea, I am restarting it. In order for the values to get updates, I have to modify the MyAppName.DLL config file. I am not sure why.